# Webform Service module : how to upload files

Tags: webforms, services

I need to create new submissions to a webform using a webservice.

It works well using the [Webform Service](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_service) module, but it seems limited to simple components only (i.e. text...).

- Is it possible to upload files with this module?
- If no, how could I achieve this by writing a custom module?